# Make contents of a <td> into a link when populated from a php sql query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using an SQL query to populate an HTML table.  The query runs fine and the table looks good.  Now I want to make contents of the first column of each row a hyperlink.  What is the best approach?  My best guess is in the snippet below and was not successful.

...

```
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";


// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</thead>";

// printing table rows  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        if($cell[0]) {
            echo "<td><a href="index2.php/$cell"></a></td>";
        }
        else
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
```

....

Comment: It is closed, I just missed it in the copy and paste.  Seems like I am missing something more than that.

Comment: No need for `\n` if you're echoing HTML, you're not closing your while loop, why are you using `$cell[0]` in the condition, but just simply calling the whole of `$cell` in your echo?

Comment: @d_ominic actually, using `\n` is best. It produces clean HTML, rather than having it all in one line. See for yourself and look at the HTML source.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see, it's been awhile since I've done PHP and forgot about that. I was assuming separate `echo` lines would be on a new line.

Comment: @d_ominic No problemo. The added benefit of using `\n` is that upon viewing HTML source (being a tool in its own right in coding), also helps during debugging to see if anything's being populated or not, and a whole bunch of other reasons/goodies ;-) cheers

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<?php

$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';

for($i=0; $i < $fields_num; $i++){

    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo '<th>{'.$field->name.'}</th>';
}

echo '</tr>';

echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {

        if($cell[0]) {
            echo '<td><a href="index2.php/'.$cell[1].'"></a></td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$cell[1].'</td>';
        }
    }
}

echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody>';

?>
```

Comment: no idea why you decided to remove OP's `\n`'s - this will produce code all in one long line of ugly HTML in source. Doing `echo "<td><a href="index2.php/$cell"></a></td>" . "\n";` is better also, etc. for all other lines of echo'd table related code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well i never used that when displaying tables and i thought may be he wrote it by mistake. thanks for pointing out, im still a learner

Comment: `\n` also helps during dubugging when looking at HTML source and is easier to find mistakes. Viewing source is in its own right, another debugging tool ;-) Not many use that as a tool; I always have and still do. Some overlook it as being a "tool".

Answer (score 0):

Your echo in your while loop should be using the individual array elements like your if statement is. You're mixing up the quotes in your echo as well. Also you should be able to just directly put PHP variables in echos, otherwise concat with a `.`

```
if ($cell[0]) {
    echo "<td><a href='index2.php/$cell[0]'></a></td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>$cell[0]</td>";
}
```

Echoing with concat:

```
echo "<td><a href='index2.php/".$cell[0]."'></a></td>";
```

etc

Not sure if you can inline echo an array, so probably best to just concat with `.`